# different results between tf.matmul and np.matmul

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

Consider the following (run on colab):

```
a = np.array([
  [ 0.9951848 +0.09801677j,  0.77301085+0.6343928j , 0.29028502+0.95694023j ],
  [-0.55557   +0.8314698j , -0.83146954+0.5555703j , -0.98078525+0.19509049j],
  [-0.47139683-0.88192123j, -0.29028472-0.9569403j , -0.09801722-0.9951847j ]
], dtype=np.complex64)

x = np.matmul(a, a.conj().T)

a_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
x_tf = tf.matmul(a_tf, tf.transpose(tf.math.conj(a_tf)))
x == x_tf
```

This yields different results:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True, False],
      [ True,  True, False],
      [ True,  True, False]])>
```

Where the inputs to `tf.matmul` & `np.matmul` are equal.
Is there a logical explanation to this?

Comment: Comparing floats with `==` is not a good idea.

Comment: Yep I compared that using `np.testing.assert_allclose` as well, it's just not the same values

Answer (score 0):

The results are the same up to a 6th digit. Try comparing like this:

```py
np.testing.assert_almost_equal(x, x_tf.numpy(), decimal=6)
```